# Getting "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" from shuffle call for Fashion-MNIST

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, shuffle, sgd

I have been trying to implement Mini-Batch optimisation on a CNN with SGD. But in trying the randomised sample selection using shuffle() I am getting the error in the Title. The code is as below. Could there be a header problem or there is something about the mismatch in data types that could lead to such an error? I have tried multiple solutions on this site but they do not seem to work. Or I'm overlooking something

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf 
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential,Input,Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
import random
from random import shuffle

(x_train,y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

n_feature = 2
n_class = 2
n_iter = 10


def make_network(n_hidden=100):
    # Initialize weights with Standard Normal random variables
    model = dict(
        W1=np.random.randn(n_feature, n_hidden),
        W2=np.random.randn(n_hidden, n_class)
    )

    return model


def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / np.exp(x).sum()


def forward(x, model):
    # Input to hidden
    h = x @ model['W1']
    # ReLU non-linearity
    h[h < 0] = 0

    # Hidden to output
    prob = softmax(h @ model['W2'])

    return h, prob

def backward(model, xs, hs, errs):
    """xs, hs, errs contain all informations (input, hidden state, error) of all data in the minibatch"""
    # errs is the gradients of output layer for the minibatch
    dW2 = hs.T @ errs

    # Get gradient of hidden layer
    dh = errs @ model['W2'].T
    dh[hs <= 0] = 0

    dW1 = xs.T @ dh

    return dict(W1=dW1, W2=dW2)

def sgd(model, X_train, y_train, minibatch_size):
    for iter in range(n_iter):
        print('Iteration {}'.format(iter))

        # Randomize data point
        X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)

        for i in range(0, X_train.shape[0], minibatch_size):
            # Get pair of (X, y) of the current minibatch/chunk
            X_train_mini = X_train[i:i + minibatch_size]
            y_train_mini = y_train[i:i + minibatch_size]

            model = sgd_step(model, X_train_mini, y_train_mini)

    return model

def sgd_step(model, X_train, y_train):
    grad = get_minibatch_grad(model, X_train, y_train)
    model = model.copy()

    # Update every parameters in our networks (W1 and W2) using their gradients
    for layer in grad:
        # Learning rate: 1e-4
        model[layer] += 1e-4 * grad[layer]

    return model

def get_minibatch_grad(model, X_train, y_train):
    xs, hs, errs = [], [], []

    for x, cls_idx in zip(X_train, y_train):
        h, y_pred = forward(x, model)

        # Create probability distribution of true label
        y_true = np.zeros(n_class)
        y_true[int(cls_idx)] = 1.

        # Compute the gradient of output layer
        err = y_true - y_pred

        # Accumulate the informations of minibatch
        # x: input
        # h: hidden state
        # err: gradient of output layer
        xs.append(x)
        hs.append(h)
        errs.append(err)

    # Backprop using the informations we get from the current minibatch
    return backward(model, np.array(xs), np.array(hs), np.array(errs))

minibatch_size = 50
n_experiment = 100

# Create placeholder to accumulate prediction accuracy
accs = np.zeros(n_experiment)

for k in range(n_experiment):
    # Reset model
    model = make_network()

    # Train the model
    model = sgd(model, X_train, y_train, minibatch_size)

    y_pred = np.zeros_like(y_test)

    for i, x in enumerate(X_test):
        # Predict the distribution of label
        _, prob = forward(x, model)
        # Get label by picking the most probable one
        y = np.argmax(prob)
        y_pred[i] = y

    # Compare the predictions with the true labels and take the percentage
    accs[k] = (y_pred == y_test).sum() / y_test.size

print('Mean accuracy: {}, std: {}'.format(accs.mean(), accs.std()))
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.shuffle()` takes the first argument (an array) and shuffles it according to the second argument (a function) as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

So what happens in your example, is that `shuffle()` is trying to call a second argument (`y_train`) to shuffle the first argument - which is not possible.

If you want to shuffle inputs into the model, I would suggest doing that in a dataloader or using `np.random.shuffle()` (so concatenating the arrays, shuffling and splitting them again to preserve order).